# Thermal energy produced by electric polarisation?

Tags: dielectric

Does DC polarisation of a dielectric liquid (stretching & rotation) cause heat to be produced and if so what is this heat production process termed scientifically?

Comment: Yes constantly doing it heats the liquid. Something of of this sort always happens in microwaves in our houses where water is the dielectric.

Comment: @user8718165 you say "constantly doing it" but what about just keeping the DC on for a period of time, does that produce heat? and if so do you know the official term for this process?

Comment: No...one time DC polarization will produce very less heat because after the molecules are aligned there will be very little to no movement. I don't know of some **official** term for this though there might exist one(I'm just not sure).

Comment: @user8718165 Thanks a lot, you've answered my question.

Comment: A better and informative answer is there, up-vote and accept it if you like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DC the electric field is non-time varying. Therefore a polarized liquid molecule (such as water) will align with the field and remain static. The initial rotation of the molecules might perhaps result in a minuscule increase in molecular kinetic energy and minuscule temperature rise. I don't know.

An alternating electric field, on the other hand, if at the right frequency, does work on the polar molecules giving them rotational kinetic energy which subsequently increases the liquid temperature. This is the principle behind microwave oven cooking.

Microwave ovens primarily operate at $2450 \text{ MHz}$, which corresponds to a photon energy level about $10^{-5}\text{ eV}$. This energy level is within the range that separates molecular rotation and torsion quantum states. (ref: Hyperphysics Interaction of radiation with matter). The rotational kinetic is randomized increasing the translational kinetic energy of water molecules. Microwave cooking is technically not a heating process (involve heat transfer) like cooking on a hot stove or in an oven where heat is transferred to the food. The alternating electric field of the microwave oven does work on the polar molecules of the food, primarily the water content of the food, giving them rotational kinetic energy.

Stretching, as you call it, is vibrational kinetic energy. That involves higher photon energy levels than a microwave oven (again refer to the Hyperphysics website). The higher energy of infrared radiation, like that inside a conventional oven, causes vibrational kinetic energy. In contrast to the microwave oven, this method of cooking does involve heat transfer, namely radiant heat transfer.

Hope this helps.